# How to store the rules of association rule in R?

Tags: r, arules

I have set of 28553 association rules generated using `arules` package of `R.` I can view them in console using `inspect(rules)`

Now how to store them in a csv(or tsv) file or into MySQL directly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`rules.dataframe <- as(yourrules, "data.frame")`